# How can the word 'priori' be used?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am only familiar with 'a priori', such as 'a priori conditions'. Now a friend uses the word as follows:

> "the supremacy of nature and the priori and inevitability of death and of history."

I do not know if maybe they mean 'priority', or maybe they mean something esoteric and beyond me.

Comment: The sentence doesn't quite make sense to me, priori or not. Could you give a complete sentence or more context?

Comment: "...glorifying the strength of woman, the supremacy of nature and the priori and inevitability of death and of history." It is quite possible it does -not- make sense!

Comment: I'd be interested to see what someone else says. I never took Latin, so I have no idea how *priori* should be used. My initial reaction, though, is that its wrong.

Comment: I am going to suggest to her that she intended 'priority'.

Comment: I think it's just a mistake. I wouldn't worry unduly about it.

Comment: As far as I know, in English "priori" is used only in the combination "a priori" from Latin.  So I agree that in this quote it is an error.

Comment: I think what may have ben intended was **...and the 'a priori' inevitability of death...**, but perhaps it was 'priority'. Whatever, I'm taking @Neil Coffey's advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe using 'priori' by itself is incorrect.  It should be 'a priori' (meaning prior to).  Similarly, using 'posteriori' by itself is incorrect.  It should be 'a posteriori' (meaning posterior to).

Here's an excerpt from the [wiki link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_priori_and_a_posteriori) that describes them:

> The terms "a priori" and "a posteriori" are used in philosophy to distinguish two
>       different types of knowledge, justification, or argument: 'a priori knowledge' is
>       known independently of experience (conceptual knowledge), and 'a posteriori 
>       knowledge' is proven through experience. Thus, they are primarily used as adjectives
>       to modify the noun "knowledge", or taken to be compound nouns that refer to types of
>       knowledge (for example, "a priori knowledge"). However, "a priori" is sometimes used
>       as an adjective to modify other nouns, such as "truth". Additionally, philosophers
>       often modify this use. For example, "apriority" and "aprioricity" are sometimes used
>       as nouns to refer (approximately) to the quality of being a priori."

Comment: Thanks. The author explains she intended priori as in Kant's priori instinct (sic). So she should use 'a priori'.